# Until they arrive / have arrived

Tags: exam-questions

Which is the correct option to replace bold part of sentence ?

> I won't be able to leave for office until they **arrive**.

A) have arrived

B) had arrived

C) will have arrived

D) no improvement

This question may be a duplicate or similar to previously asked question but I tried hard searching through ELL SE  for previously asked queation and clear my doubt from them but I am still confused . I learned from those questions that the tense after until is same as tense before until but FUTURE tense is an exception so that rules out option C but what about option A, B and D ? The given sentence is in future ( won't =  short of will not ) but future tense can't be used after until so what should I use ? I googled for the answer but got more confused as a site mentioned option A as correct option and other one mentioned option D as correct answer. In case of past and present the rule is simple to use same tense on later side of *until* but what's the rule for future tense ?

Comment: "arrive" indicates a point in the (then) present time, which seems to fit the context. So D).

Comment: @user3169 But why option A doesn't fit ?

Comment: A better question would be "Why option A?" There is no context that justifies using PP, so simpler is better.

Comment: Options B and C are impossible. Option A is equally acceptable to the original sentence. So I suppose the answer is D.